# Custom NSView Drag Destination

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, osx-lion

I'm trying to create a simple NSView that will allow a folder from Finder to be dragged onto it.  A folder path is the *only* thing I want the view to accept as a draggable item.  I've been trying to follow the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragdestination.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000977-BAJBJFBG), but so far nothing's working.  So far, I've just tried to get the view to work with any file type, but I can't even seem to do that.  Here's what I have so far:

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect])
    {
        NSLog(@"getting called");
        [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSPasteboardTypeString,
                                       NSPasteboardTypePDF,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeTIFF,
                                       NSPasteboardTypePNG,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeRTF,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeRTFD,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeHTML,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeTabularText,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeFont,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeRuler,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeColor,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeSound,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeMultipleTextSelection,
                                       NSPasteboardTypeFindPanelSearchOptions, nil]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL) prepareForDragOperation: (id<NSDraggingInfo>) sender
{
    NSLog(@"preparing for drag");

    return YES;
}
```

The `initWithFrame:` method is getting called, but when I try to drag into the view the `prepareForDragOperation:` method doesn't ever seem to get called.  My questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?  Why isn't `prepareForDragOperation:` ever getting called?
2. What do I need to do to get the drag operation to only support dragging folders?

**Update**

I updated my `registerForDraggedTypes:` method with every type I could find.  It now looks like this:

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSPasteboardTypeString,
                               NSPasteboardTypePDF,
                               NSPasteboardTypeTIFF,
                               NSPasteboardTypePNG,
                               NSPasteboardTypeRTF,
                               NSPasteboardTypeRTFD,
                               NSPasteboardTypeHTML,
                               NSPasteboardTypeTabularText,
                               NSPasteboardTypeFont,
                               NSPasteboardTypeRuler,
                               NSPasteboardTypeColor,
                               NSPasteboardTypeSound,
                               NSPasteboardTypeMultipleTextSelection,
                               NSPasteboardTypeFindPanelSearchOptions,
                               NSStringPboardType,
                               NSFilenamesPboardType,
                               NSPostScriptPboardType,
                               NSTIFFPboardType,
                               NSRTFPboardType,
                               NSTabularTextPboardType,
                               NSFontPboardType,
                               NSRulerPboardType,
                               NSFileContentsPboardType,
                               NSColorPboardType,
                               NSRTFDPboardType,
                               NSHTMLPboardType,
                               NSURLPboardType,
                               NSPDFPboardType,
                               NSVCardPboardType,
                               NSFilesPromisePboardType,
                               NSMultipleTextSelectionPboardType, nil]];
```

I've noticed that the `prepareForDragOperation:` method isn't getting called when I drag a folder into the view.  Did I miss a step?

Comment: Interesting. `NSFilenamesPboardType` is the one which is working for me. I'm using `acceptDrop:` in an outline view. `prepareForDragOperation:` is not being called on my outline view, though. Have you tried implementing `performDragOperation:` and `concludeDragOperation:`, too?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a simple little drag & drop view meeting those criteria:

`MDDragDropView.h`:

```
@interface MDDragDropView : NSView {
    BOOL        isHighlighted;
}

@property (assign, setter=setHighlighted:) BOOL isHighlighted;

@end
```

`MDDragDropView.m`:

```
@implementation MDDragDropView

@dynamic isHighlighted;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]) {

        NSArray *paths = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        for (NSString *path in paths) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSString *utiType = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
                                       typeOfFile:path error:&error];
            if (![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] 
                      type:utiType conformsToType:(id)kUTTypeFolder]) {

                [self setHighlighted:NO];
                return NSDragOperationNone;
            }
        }
    }
    [self setHighlighted:YES];
    return NSDragOperationEvery;
}
```

And the rest of the methods:

```
- (void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
}


- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender  {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)isHighlighted {
    return isHighlighted;
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)value {
    isHighlighted = value;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    if (isHighlighted) {
        [NSBezierPath setDefaultLineWidth:6.0];
        [[NSColor keyboardFocusIndicatorColor] set];
        [NSBezierPath strokeRect:self.frame];
    }
}

@end
```

The reason `prepareForDragOperation:` isn't being called is that the dragging destination sequence follows a precise set of steps, and if the earlier steps aren't implemented, or are implemented but return a "stop the drag operation" type of answer, the later methods are never reached. (In your case, it doesn't appear that you've implemented the `draggingEntered:` method, which would need to return something other than `NSDragOperationNone` to continue on in the sequence).

Before `prepareForDragOperation:` is sent, the view is first sent a series of dragging destination messages:

A single `- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender`.

Depending on the `NSDragOperation` mask returned from that method, the following will be called if it's implemented in your class:

Multiple `- (NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender`.

Depending on the `NSDragOperation` mask returned from that method, then `prepareForDragOperation:` will be called.

Comment: So, that's an NSImageView. Does it work if it's just an NSView?

Comment: Sure. (I've changed it to `NSView` to make it a more general case). In most cases, I've used `NSImageView` as the "image well" style of image view provides a nice drop target.

Comment: You might want to be careful with `[NSBezierPath strokeRect:frame]` as it draws the frame around the invalidated part of the screen, not necessarily the current view (could be a subview).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `NSURLPboardType` to register for stuff being dropped from the Finder (when I drag a file or a folder to my application, it receives them as urls)
Try this. And if it works, it'll solve your second problem : just check if the URL is a folder to accept or reject the drop :

```
// if item is an NSURL * :
CFURLHasDirectoryPath((CFURLRef)item)
// returns true if item is the URL of a folder.
```